# Position 2 arrows fixed to the outside of the HTML page container with CSS - screen size

Tags: html, css, screen, resolution

I am trying to create a HTML page slider, so I have my container div, then sitting on the outside, on the left I have a Previous Icon and on the right I have a Next icon.

My problem is, when I resize the window to smaller screens the icons move into the center of my container, I want them to stay position fixed to the outside of the container at all times when resized.

My container code: -

```
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 449px;
```

Next and previous code:

```
a.vehicleSliderLeft {background: url('../img/slider_arrow_left.png'); 
             width: 55px; height: 112px; left: 270px; background-position:0px; 
             background-repeat: no-repeat; position: fixed; top: 420px;}    

a.vehicleSliderRight {background: url('../img/slider_arrow_right.png'); 
             width: 55px; height: 112px; right: 270px; background-position:0px; 
             background-repeat: no-repeat; position: fixed; top: 420px;}
```

Any ideas? cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the main container `position: relative` and then position the arrow elements inside the container with `position: absolute`.

This then allows you to manipulate where you put both arrows on the page using `right: x , left: x , top: x , bottom: x.` where x is any number or percentage.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LZG3R/3/

Source: [Learn CSS Position in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: Is it possible to get them to sit outside the container? Rather than in it?

Comment: take a look at them, they are outside the continer

Comment: my image still seems to disappear behind the body'a background. As i nudge it along in 'inspect element' is moves behind.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
.container{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: none;
}

a.vehicleSliderLeft {
    float: left;
}    

a.vehicleSliderRight {
    float: right;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EhdkP/1/

Answer (score 0):

inside a main div you can keep each element in separate divs specifying the positions of each div specifying the widths in percentage